# asp.net CodeBehind variable to JavaScript doesn't work on production IIS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis

> var mAnTarih = JSON.stringify('<%=jsonTarih%>');

It worked on Vs2012. It worked on local IIS. But didn't worked on production server.
Asp.Net Web Form app use .Net 2 framework.

The Production IIS server I get error as:

> "jsonTarih" is not define.

Any help.

Kind Regards

Comment: What is jsonTarih? Is it marked as `public`?

Comment: Hi mason, first it was protected in .Net Framework 4. But when I try to re-develop for .net framework 2 (because production IIS uses .Net Framework 2 in classic app pool) I change in my VS2012 as public. I had problem on VS2012 and local IIS and change to public. Then In production server I use as is (public) and get the same error. Then I change the code behind to protected and I still get same problem. I couldn't figured out what was the problem. It worked on VS2012 and local IIS but not in production.